# Adding to immutable HashSet

Tags: scala, scala-collections, immutable-collections

Sorry guys, I recently saw an example in "Programming in Scala", 2nd Edition on page 685, which seemed strange to me:

```
var hashSet: Set[C] = new collection.immutable.HashSet
hashSet += elem1
```

How is it possible to add something an immutable collection? I tried on REPL and it worked ok!

```
> scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_11).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> var s : Set[Int] = collection.immutable.HashSet()
s: Set[Int] = Set()

scala> s += 1324

scala> println(s)
Set(1324)
```

The stranger fact is that += operator is not defined in *immutable.HashSet* api page. Could anybody please help me understand what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Cannot speak to how `+=` is handled syntax-wise, but adding to an immutable HashSet is just like appending to an immutable String: You get a new instance with the modified contents.

Answer (score 5):

You are not adding to the `HashSet`. You are assigning to `hashSet`, which is perfectly fine, since `hashSet` is a `var`, not a `val`.

[Section 6.12.4 *Assignment Operators* of the Scala Language Specification (SLS)](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators) explains how such compound assignment operators are desugared:

```
l ω= r
```

(where `ω` is any sequence of operator characters other than `<`, `>`, `!` and doesn't start with `=`) gets desugared to

```
l.ω=(r)
```

*iff* `l` has or is implicitly convertible to an object that has a member named `ω=`.

Otherwise, it gets desugared to

```
l = l.ω(r)
```

(except `l` is guaranteed to be only evaluated once), if that typechecks.

This allows something like `+=` to work like it does in other languages but still be overridden to do something different.

Answer (score 3):

Observe this:

```
scala> var hashSet: Set[Int] = new collection.immutable.HashSet
hashSet: Set[Int] = Set()

scala> val set2 = hashSet + 1234
set2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1234)

scala> set2
res20: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1234)

scala> hashSet
res21: Set[Int] = Set()
```

So nothing gets added to the immutable hashSet. `hashSet` is the same as it was when constructed. `+` returns a new set altogether and the original set is unchanged.

When you do `hashSet += 1234`, it is a scala shorthand for (note no method `+=` exists in [HashSet](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.HashSet)):

```
val temp = hashSet + 1234
hashSet = temp
```

`+=` will work for any class which follows [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators) protocol. In short when you do `a += 12`. `a` must have a method `+` which returns the same type as `a`'s and `a` should be assignable (i.e. a `var`. It does not work for val. Try this: `val i = 23; i+=1`).

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

You have a `var` so you can reassign to it. So `+=` in this case will be translated to

```
hashSet = hashSet + elem
```

just like other types, as long as `+` is defined on them

```
var i = 0
i += 1
i = i + 1
```

### Details

`immutable.HashSeth` has [`+`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashSet@+(elem1:A,elem2:A,elems:A*):scala.collection.immutable.HashSet[A]) method which

> Creates a new set with an additional element, unless the element is
>   already present.

according to [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashSet).

There is no `+=` method defined in this class, so `+=` will be a synthetic method [given to you by compiler](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators) which acts as an [operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_operators.htm) simply calling the `+` method on the left operand by passing the right operand and assigning the result back to the left operand.